# SSRS - Credentials on reports after deploy do not match source rdl file

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

The project I am working on has been having the issue of stored credentials in the rdl files not being reflected on the server we deploy to and it seems to be inconsistent in its behavior. We are NOT using a shared data source because we have to generate the data source connection dynamically so each report has its own data source embedded (even though they are all identical) and it has the credentials stored. I look in VS at the rdl file and see the credentials are stored, deploy to our test server, look on the test server and the credentials are set to "Not Required". Other strange thing is this doesn't happen to all reports all the time, some reports keep their credentials but not every time. It all seems very random.

Some settings and facts about the project that may be useful:

- Using SQL Server 2008 R2
- Using Visual Studio 2012 to deploy
- ReportProject setting OverwriteDatasets = True
- ReportProject setting OverwriteDataSources = True

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issues, delete the report on the SSRS server first, then deploy the report.  SSRS does retain certain attributes of report it is very inconsistent when it does this and this is more of a workaround than an answer, but it works for me.